# Bootstrap modal height

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Maybe I do not undestand something, but does bootstrap modal callbacks work?

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    set_valign()
    alert($('.modal-content').height())
});
```

This always return 0.

CSS:

```
.modal-content { 

    text-align:center;min-height:100%;width:100%;
}
```

I try to set position:relative, but also return always 0.

Comment: Could you provide markup please?

Comment: Yes it works. Whats returing $('.modal-content').outerHeight() and $('.modal-content').innerHeight()?

Comment: ok I got it ... I add overflow:hidden and it get height now.